# Existing list of all punctuation/whitespace chars in C#

Tags: c#, char, whitespace, punctuation

I'm splitting a string on all punctuation and whitespace characters. Rather than build a complicated *(?)* regex to match what C# considers "punctuation" and "whitespace" characters, I'm using the `char.IsPunctuation` and `char.IsWhiteSpace` methods to get the characters from the string that are punctuation/whitespace.

Basically, this is what I'm doing - building an array of punctuation and whitespace characters, which I later use to split the string.

```
return text.Where(c => char.IsPunctuation(c) || char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();
```

I did it this way originally because I couldn't find anywhere there was a static list/array of chars that C# considers punctuation or whitespace. In the [MSDN documentation for `char.IsPunctuation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.ispunctuation), it lists the Unicode code points it considers punctuation, but my question is: does that list exist anywhere *in the .NET code?* That I could reference instead of building it from the input string every time?

Comment: Why you build it everytime instead of re-using the array?

Comment: See how it's implemented https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c7c15f7c2c55578b4e64450e4c236f5f59360827/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Char.cs#L748, it's based on the Unicode Category.

Comment: Or you could use the `\p{P}` character class in a regex to match punctuation characters.  `[\s\p{P}]` would match any character that's either whitespace or punctuation. Use `Regex.Split` instead of `String.Split`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Because every string may have different punctuation/whitespace characters in it, and I'm not persisting the array anywhere.

@madreflection I'm not actually doing a `string.Split`, I just simplified my explanation to that. I'm most concerned about performance with very long strings, and AFAIK regex doesn't usually perform as well as plain string operations on very large strings.

Comment: It greatly depends on the input and the pattern. Try it before you reject it. Anyway, it might help if you posted what you're actually trying to do. This may be an X/Y problem, i.e. you're stuck solving problems brought on by a specific solution rather than finding a proper solution.

Comment: If you are searching a very long string to extract whitespace/punctuation characters, and then using those characters to process the very long string, you are doing a lot of work twice.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `String.Split` with an endless list of characters and determining them with LINQ before you split, which is really not efficient, you could use a different approach using a `StringBuilder` and enumerate the characters just once. For example:

```
public static string[] SplitWhiteSpacesAndPunctuations(string text, StringSplitOptions options = StringSplitOptions.None)
{
    List<string> list = new(Math.Max(text.Length/10, 4));
    StringBuilder sb = new(10);
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c) || char.IsPunctuation(c))
        {
            AddStringAndClearStringBuilder();
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }

    AddStringAndClearStringBuilder();

    return list.ToArray();

    void AddStringAndClearStringBuilder()
    {
        if (sb.Length == 0 && options == StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) return;
        list.Add(sb.ToString());
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3eLI9d